# Ubuntu installation with Intel RST

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, ssd, intel-rst

I am currently using an ASUS VivoBook S15 (S530FN). My laptop came with a 1TB HDD and Intel Optane Memory, that I have changed with a 256GB NVMe SSD. So actually I have a 256 GB SSD (with Windows 10 Home) and a 1TB HDD that I use as secondary drive.
Today I decided to install "Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS" but when installation starts up the following notification pops up:

[image: Turn off RST error].

I followed the official ubuntu help page: https://help.ubuntu.com/rst/ , but I could not manually recreate the bootloader file because my partitions were not as described in that page.
Watching some of the comments at the end of the page it seems a deprecated guide.
Someone can tell me if it's possible in my situation to keep Windows 10 on the SSD and to install Ubuntu (or any Linux distro) on the HDD?

**EDIT**: I tried to switch to AHCI modifying registry and changing the Controller Mode from BIOS. But I could not go further because Windows stopped booting correctly and the commands written in the ubuntu help page did not fix the problem.

Comment: Intel RST was only required when you had the Intel Optane drive installed.  Intel RST isn't required for a typical SSD.  What is the value of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\iaStorV\?

Comment: I tried to switch to AHCI modifying registry and changing the Controller Mode from BIOS. But I could not go further because Windows stopped booting correctly and the commands written in the ubuntu help page did not fix the problem.

Comment: You are right, I am sorry. I will edit the question.

Comment: So I can't tell if you have a working Windows installation or not, but the guide is accurate, and should have worked.  Of course you also had to have uninstalled Intel RST drivers.

Comment: The value of iaStorV was "3" previously, but I changed them to "0" before changing controller mode in BIOS.

Comment: I presume you didn't remove the Intel RST software that had been installed before you made this configuration change?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129132/discussion-between-sergio-and-ramhound).

Comment: But if you do a safe boot first to update Windows, then boot to UEFI/BIOS and change to AHCI and finally boot normally, it works
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-installation-on-computers-with-intel-r-rst-enabled/15347  & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233623/workaround-to-install-ubuntu-20-04-with-intel-rst-systems

Comment: I followed @oldfred advises and continued on https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233623/workaround-to-install-ubuntu-20-04-with-intel-rst-systems. All worked fine and now I am writing from Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

I am answering my own question with the following steps thanks to @oldfred, source of solution: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233623/workaround-to-install-ubuntu-20-04-with-intel-rst-systems.

You've got a single HDD/SSD set up in RAID (RST) mode, and the Ubuntu installer won't recognize your HDD/SSD until you switch your disk setting in the BIOS from RAID to AHCI.

Making that switch comes with some problems though, as Windows will no longer boot.

Solution:

- Right-click the Windows Start Menu. Choose `Command Prompt (Admin)`
- If you don’t see `Command Prompt` listed, it’s because you have already been updated to a later version of Windows.  If so, use this method instead to get to the Command Prompt:
- Click the Start Button and type `cmd`
- Right-click the result and select `Run as administrator`
- Type this command and press ENTER: `bcdedit /set {current} safeboot minimal`

  - If this command does not work for you, try `bcdedit /set safeboot minimal`
- Restart the computer and enter BIOS Setup (the key to press varies
  between systems).
- Change the SATA Operation mode to AHCI from either IDE or RAID
  (again, the language varies).
- Save changes and exit Setup and Windows will automatically boot to
  Safe Mode.
- Right-click the Windows Start Menu once more. Choose `Command Prompt (Admin)`
- Type this command and press ENTER: `bcdedit /deletevalue {current} safeboot`
- If you had to try the alternate command above, you will likely need
  to do so here also:
  `bcdedit /deletevalue safeboot`
- Reboot once more and Windows will automatically start with AHCI
  drivers enabled.

Comment: You can use **msconfig** too. It allows you to set "Safe boot - Minimal" graphically and then later revert the change without the need to use the command line tool called bcdedit unless you really prefer it.