# How can I turn off Intel RST without losing all my data?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, intel-rst

I am trying to install Linux on my computer that already has stock Windows 10 on it. The Ubuntu installer asks me to disable Intel Rapid Storage Technology. The only way I have found to disable RST is in the boot menu. But in that menu, changing the storage mode from RST to AHCI warns about losing all data on the disk.

I don't want to lose any data or the Windows on the disk. How can I disable RST while keeping my data and OS safe?

Any workaround that allows to install Ubuntu without disabling Intel RST is also welcome.

Edit: The PC is Lenovo Ideapad S340-15IIL

[image]

Comment: You cant.  Backup up your data.

Comment: Thanks. I have two drives. Can I check which one has iRST? I want to know which data I have to back up.

Comment: See here https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-installation-on-computers-with-intel-r-rst-enabled/15347

Comment: Thanks for the Discourse link. I am going through it. Do all distributions of Linux need RST disabled? Or is there a common distribution that can be installed over RST?

Comment: Also, when you say back-up your data, I can copy my files and documents to another disk. But what about the OS? Is there a way I can somehow "save" the Windows 10 and all the installed software, to restore the system without needing a new Windows?

Comment: I don't think you can install a Linux distro to dualboot without disabling RST https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/no4m0f/is_there_any_linux_distros_that_can_use_intel_rst/

Comment: @AbdullahBaig I don't know if it is an option for you but I'd simply remove the current drive and stick another drive in the PC. I am kinda lazy. It is also possible to create an image of everything currently on the drive and store that on another harddrive. Google "windows 10 disk imaging cloning" and "windows 10 full backup" for more info.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gantendo. I think "disk image cloning" is what is good for me. I just want to keep the original Windows and save the hassle of installing everything again.

Comment: You can have Linux on Windows with WSL.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu installation with Intel RST](https://superuser.com/questions/1672500/ubuntu-installation-with-intel-rst)

Comment: Thanks @harrymc, but I would prefer to install a complete Linux, not run it on top of Windows.

Comment: @ChanganAuto this link describes exactly my problem. I am going through it. Thanks very much. ❤

Comment: @Keltari I have done it. See ChanganAuto's answer below. It just took 2-3 minutes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Whenever installing OSes or doing anything that can potentially mess with the current drives and/or bootloaders, having proper up-to-date, versioned, and known to work (recoverable) backups is a MUST, period.**

Users should always have backups of all files they can't afford to loose. **Drives can and do fail anytime**.

Now, specifically regarding your question, and unlike some comments seem to point out, **you can enable AHCI support in an already installed Windows** and then install a Linux distro in dual-boot. There is no difference in performance.

Here's the currently recommended method as posted by the [user Heynnema at AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1233644/1210606):

- Right-click the Windows Start Menu. Choose Command Prompt (Admin).
- If you don’t see Command Prompt listed, it’s because you have already been updated to a later version of Windows.  If so, use this method instead to get to the Command Prompt:
- Click the Start Button and type cmd
- Right-click the result and select Run as administrator
- Type this command and press ENTER: bcdedit /set {current} safeboot minimal
- If this command does not work for you, try bcdedit /set safeboot minimal
- Restart the computer and enter BIOS Setup (the key to press varies between systems).
- Change the SATA Operation mode to AHCI from either IDE or RAID (again, the language varies).
- Save changes and exit Setup and Windows will automatically boot to Safe Mode.
- Right-click the Windows Start Menu once more. Choose Command Prompt (Admin)
- Type this command and press ENTER: bcdedit /deletevalue {current} safeboot
- If you had to try the alternate command above, you will likely need to do so here also: bcdedit /deletevalue safeboot
- Reboot once more and Windows will automatically start with AHCI drivers enabled.

Additional source: http://triplescomputers.com/blog/uncategorized/solution-switch-windows-10-from-raidide-to-ahci-operation/

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will have to check if this works for me. But I am not familiar with the backup process for the whole OS. So it may take quite a few days until I get fully comfortable with back up options and try disabling RST.

Comment: It worked like a charm!! Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an older answer, but I will share my experiences.  My computer is a HP Envy TE01-1287CB.

I followed the steps listed and changing from *Intel Raid* was greyed out and not an option for me after setting to safeboot with the command `bcdedit /set safeboot minimal` and restarting the computer.

If you are in a similar situation, when you go through Computer Management then Disk Management in Windows 11, you may find that there is a smaller drive, in my case it was a 16GB disk that showed.

After inspecting the motherboard, I found that there was a NVME 16GB Intel Optane disk.  I removed that, then went into BIOS and found that I could then change the SATA option to AHCI.

So, I would recommend that these steps be added to the how to change from RAID/RST to ACHI.

The steps would be as follows for Windows 11:

1. Type Computer Management in the search bar and select *open*.
2. Select *Disk Management*.
3. Look for a single smaller disk listed (16-20GB), if found:

   3a. Check motherboard for Intel Optane drive in a M.2 drive slot

   3b. Remove the disk if found.

   3c. *if you have another M.2 disk, you can install it in that drive slot*
4. In the search bar type: cmd
5. select *run as administrator*
6. type: `bcdedit /set safeboot minimal`
7. Restart the computer and enter BIOS Setup (the key to press varies between systems)
8. Change the SATA Operation mode to AHCI from either IDE or RAID (again, the language varies).
9. Save changes and exit Setup and Windows will automatically boot to Safe Mode.
10. Type cmd in the search bar and *run as administrator*
11. type: `bcdedit /deletevalue safeboot`
12. Reboot once more and Windows will automatically start with AHCI drivers enabled.
13. With AHCI enabled, you can now install any version of Linux you like.

***Note: This of course, will remove any drive speed advantages that Optane gives when using the Intel Optane system.***

Cheers and I hope this helps others that found themselves in my same situation.