# How can I switch from UEFI to BIOS?

Tags: boot, bios, uefi, lenovo-laptop

I am trying to install Linux and I need to use legacy BIOS mode. I tried the common method shown on the manufacturer's [support page](https://support.lenovo.com/mo/en/solutions/ht503657), but the UEFI/legacy setting seems to be disabled on my PC. The Bot Mode row is black. I cannot select it with up down keys.

How can I enable the UEFI/legacy option?

If it helps, my PC is Lenovo Ideapad S340IIL and Intel RST is enabled on it.

[image]

Comment: Your other computer supported CSM, your new computer, does not.  Windows 8.1 was almost released 10 years ago.  Every major OS supports UEFI.

Comment: All major Linux distributions support UEFI.

Comment: You typically have to update UEFI and turn off Intel RST/Optane. But if dual booting with Windows first install AHCI driver into Windows or it will not work. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1144049/ubuntu-on-lenovo-ideapad-s340-intel-i3-8-gig  & https://superuser.com/questions/1672500/ubuntu-installation-with-intel-rst?noredirect=1#comment2565531_1672500

Comment: @oldfred - In this case the author’s hardware doesn’t support CSM/Legacy Boot

Comment: Does not matter if UEFI or BIOS, still need to turn off RST. And always good idea to make sure you have latest UEFI firmware & if SSD latest SSD firmware. Another Lenovo, may be similar? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1291280/after-running-boot-repair-and-disabeling-secure-boot-still-not-booting-to-grub

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I enable the UEFI/legacy option?

You cannot.  Your hardware does not support Compatibility Support Module (CSM). Your device has a 10th generation Intel Core processor, per Intel's announcement in July 2020, your processor was only validated to support UEFI.

> Intel previously announced that in 2020 they are phasing out support for legacy Basic Input/Output System (BIOS) boot mode. This means that many of the Lenovo products launching in 2020 will no longer support the Legacy Boot option in BIOS. The only Boot option that will be supported on those products is Unified Extensible Firmware Interface (UEFI).
>
> Applicable Brands:
>
> - ThinkStation
> - ThinkCentre
> - ThinkPad
> - ThinkBook
> - Lenovo
> - ideacentre
> - ideapad
> - LEGION

Source: [Legacy BIOS Boot Support Removed in Lenovo 2020 products](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/ideapad-s-series-netbooks/s340-15api/solutions/ht510878-legacy-bios-boot-support-removed-in-lenovo-2020-products)

Intel Announcement: [Legacy BIOS Boot Support Removal for Intel Platforms Technical Advisory](https://cdrdv2.intel.com/v1/dl/getContent/630266?wapkw=630266)

> Starting with client platforms launching in 2020. Intel will no longer be supporting legacy Basic Input/output System (BIOS) mode.
>
> - This Includes 10th generation Intel platforms launching in 2020 and all future platforms.

Comment: @AbdullahBaig - Your PC most definitely DOES NOT support Legacy mode.  As for the reason Boot Mode option is still present in the list of options, I have no idea, I just assume the developers are lazy.  If it supported Legacy Boot/CSM/Compatibility Mode you would have been able to change the Boot Mode.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. I understand the situation now. The notion that my PC does not support Legacy mode is based on the switch option greyed out in the Boot menu and the manufacturer's announcement. This makes it highly likely to be true. But is there a setting or a status check in my PC which I can check and be 100 % sure about it? That would help me to have full closure on this issue.

Comment: @AbdullahBaig - I have no idea what you are looking for, I have provided the announcement that indicates, that 10th generation Intel Core processors were only validated to support UEFI mode.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, the 10 gen processor nails it.

Comment: It is entirely possible that whatever motherboard the manufacturer makes *could* somehow be designed to support 9th and 10th generation processors. Having that option available would allow the supported group to use it.

Comment: @Mokubai - Are 9th and 10th are on entirely different sockets.  What is more likely is that a small subset of Intel products released in 2020 did support CSM.  Just because Intel did not validate it to support CSM does not mean MSI/ASUS/Gigabyte/etc. did not validate it.  Lenovo decided against validating their products.

Comment: @Ramhound For removable LGA socket type processors sure, but the [U class](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/datasheets/8th-gen-core-family-datasheet-vol-1.pdf) use BGA1528 rather than LGA1151 (9th) or LGA1220 (10th) and potentially includes processors from 8th through to 10th generation: https://www.cpu-infos.net/intel/intel-cpus-by-socket-type/bga-1528/ but your point that *some* processors could have still have some level of support is valid too, as manufacturers do tend to retain support for businesses that really *need* it.

Comment: It would be great if anyone could guide me how to check if my computer supports CSM.

Comment: @AbdullahBaig you've found it. In your BIOS an option is there but disabled and so not supported. Ramhound has also stated that your processor does not support it.

Comment: @AbdullahBaig - Your system does not support CSM.